# When ads are unecessary for buying a product because you already know the product yourself

Tags: idioms, phrase-request

We have a very popular proverb which says:

> A good product is not the sales person who recommends that you to buy it and compliments a lot about it. A good product has a high quality and the buyer would not need any compliments to buy it. They would choose these products themselves without any suggestions or specific advertisements.

We even use this proverb when we are talking about a person's qualities. For example, imagine two colleagues talking about a company's new member who they have heard lots of good things about him/her. One of them says:

> - Tom (his/her direct manager who has hired the new member) said that he/she is a real talent.

The other one says:

> - [the proverb in question]

**Question**: I was wondering if someone could let me know what do the AmE speakers say in such a situation and is there any equivalent saying or particular proverb for that concept in AE at all?

---

Apparently, there are some translations which can convey the message, but I have no idea if they work in AmE or not.  I have no idea if they are contemporary, or how well known they are or if they are considered old-fashioned.

> - A good car doesn’t need a salesman, it sells itself.
> - A good wine needs no buss.

Comment: How many questions have you got in all? Three? Then you should make a thread for each question.

Comment: I will remove the downvote when you make your question clearer. You seem to want to reply to some hype about a new employee with a phrase roughly comparable to "We will have to see for ourselves" (from your title: "...because you have to know the product yourself")

Comment: I think the question is pretty clear. What is a phrase along the lines of "it sells itself" that can possibly apply to people as well as objects?

Comment: @CookieMonster interesting! How did it sound to you like multiple separated question in a manner that I had to bring it up in several threads?! ;)

Comment: @TRomano is it possible to be clearer at all? If yes, then please kindly change my question so that I could learn more! Please give us non-native speakers a little right.

Comment: I fail to see how this question is "too broad"?  OP is asking if there is an English equivalent for a particular proverb, with quite a bit of supporting detail about how and where it's used in his own native language.  It can be answered with one proverb that spans these two use cases, or two separate proverbs to cover these two use cases.  Either way it's a clear, simple, and targeted question that can be easily answered.

Comment: You might want to ask this question on the [English Language and Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com) SE—English approximations of non-English sayings are a pretty popular question type there. Tag it with *phrase requests* and *idioms* and add a little information about where you've already looked for an answer (where you found the two possibilities you mention) and I think you'd have a popular question. (I'm not saying the question doesn't belong here, just that you could ask it there if you want.)

Comment: If I've misinterpreted the meaning in the title, it was a little too  wordy, just edit the title. Hope the edit helps, the question shows thought, research and care. I like it!

Comment: If James P's interpretation of your question (i.e., What is a phrase along the lines of "it sells itself" that can possibly apply to people as well as objects?) is correct, I don't think your example matches the phrase/proverb well, e.g., A: "Tom said that Jim is a real talent." B: "[proverb which roughly means 'It sells itself']". -- If I were B, I might simply say, "I know (, right?)"

Comment: "Time will tell." "His performance will speak for itself." "The results will speak for themselves." Do any of these help?

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang it works here, but I'm looking for a closer saying in AmE. :)

Comment: @A-friend What do you mean? Those *are* sayings used even in American English. Do you mean American slang?

Comment: I would need a native speakers confirmation on Teacher KSHuang's post.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **["(Has to) speak for itself"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/speaks-for-itself)**:

> If something speaks for itself, it is clear and needs no further
>   explanation

For example:

> Don't tell me which one is good, I can see it and it **has to speak for
>   itself**.

Here is another example from [TheFreeDictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/speak+for+itself):

> I think my work these past few months **speaks for itself** and makes me
>   more than qualified for this position.

You can also use **["the proof of the pudding is in the eating"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/proof-of-the-pudding-is-in-the-eating)**:

> said to mean that you can only judge the quality of something after
>   you have tried, used, or experienced it

And here is another one: **["A good wine needs no bush"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/good+wine+needs+no+bush)** (I think it's less common):

> An item of good quality needs no advertisement.

Answer (score -1):

> Tom (his/her direct manager who has hired the new member) said that he/she is a real talent.

The other one should say:

> **He's a natural.** / **She's a natural.**

For the other questions, please create separate threads.

Comment: I humbly disagree. I'm quite sure one can say it in a much better way @cookie monster in AmE. Meanwhile how it can encompass the product example?

Comment: There are no other questions, please see the edit history. The post needed a little pruning and reorganisation.

Comment: Suggestions for improving the question, like breaking it into multiple questions, should be made in comments Cookie Monster. That way when the author updates their question, your answer won't have obsolete content in it.